# laravel-shopify osiset Uninstallation webhook not getting work

Tags: shopify, laravel-8, shopify-app

https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/wiki/Installation
I follow the step to add Uninstallation Job, But not getting any webhook call after uninstalling the app.
So when I try to install getting an error.
There’s no page at this address.

Can anyone help me with an example to check or debug that uninstallation Process?

Answer (score 0):

It is an exercise in two parts. One, your App needs to listen to an endpoint. Create an endpoint that accepts webhooks and has the capability of ensuring security with the Shopify HMAC. Test your endpoint is working with Postman or some other simple too. By working we mean NOT 404. Now setup your webhook with the App API key you have, in your test store. Usually this is done by installing your App. Now uninstall. Watch your endpoint logs. Nothing much else to it.

If you are getting 404 errors, your App is not working properly. Work on that aspect of your web development before trying more complex things.

Answer (score 0):

Did you type in  ‘php artisan vendor:publish --tag=shopify-jobs‘

And also check if there is an Job at ‘App/Jobs/AppUninstalledJob‘

Also make sure that your shopify-config looks like this:

```
'webhooks' => [
    [
        'topic' => env('SHOPIFY_WEBHOOK_1_TOPIC', 'app/uninstalled'),
        'address' => env('SHOPIFY_WEBHOOK_1_ADDRESS', env('APP_URL').'webhook/app-uninstalled')
    ]
]
```

Now you should also be aware of the fact that the webhook will not work on your local installation. If you went through all of the steps correctly and deploy your app to a public Server it will work.